# Django: Match two models by same field they have

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models. `User` model

```
class User(TimeStampedModel):
    phone_number = models.CharField(
        _('Phone number'),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        max_length=30,
    )
    reservations = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Reservation',
        related_name='Users',
        verbose_name=_('Reservations'),
    )
```

and `Reservation` model:

```
class Reservation(TimeStampedModel):
    phone_number = models.CharField(
        _('Phone number'),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        max_length=30,
    )
```

As you see there is `ManyToManyField` relationship between them.
Here I need to get one `user` that `phone_number` is same with `Reservation` model's `phone_number`

How can I get that one `user`

Comment: Please use a `ForeignKey`, not a phone number: if later the phone number changes, you can no longer link to that user.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# retrieving the first reservation
# You can use .get(id=xxx) instead of first
# if you want to use an specific reservation
reservation = Reservation.objects.first()
# Get the first user related with the reservation
reservation.Users.first()
```

I recommend that you add unique=True to phone_number in the User model to avoid duplicates. Also to ensure that a reservation only belongs to one user.